# Code::Blocks project compiling on multiple platforms

Tags: makefile, linker, mingw, cross-platform, codeblocks

I have a Code::Blocks project using SDL that for compiling requires including `-lmingw32` on Windows and not including it for Linux. My project file currently specifies which libraries to be linked. Since I don't want to modify my project file for different platforms, what is the best practice here? Is it possible to configure the project by platform, or should I use makefiles instead?

Comment: Common practice linux is, I believe, to create a `configure` script which will generate a `makefile` from a template. Or you can try to see how CMake works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code::Blocks has the ability to [add build targets](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Creating_a_new_project#Adding_a_new_build_target), which can be used for different linker settings.